# thispagestyle plain without header/footer

Tags: header-footer

I'm inserting an empty page with page number the following way:

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\mbox{}
```

Now, my header and footer are also showing up in the empty page, but I defined my header and footer with use of the `\fancyhead` and `fancyfoot` within an `\fancypagestyle{plain}`. How, do I get rid of the header and footer while inserting an empty page?

Comment: did you try `\thispagestyle{empty}`?

Comment: I think it's \thispagestyle{empty}. But I don't know how it works with fancy.

Comment: Yes, the `\thispagestyle{empty}` works fine to get an empty page, but I need the page number as well. I don't want to do this manually.

Comment: your comments don't seem to match your question.  The footer normally contains the page number so if you want the page number you want to use a page style that has the number, such as the original plain page style. if you have redefined plain to be a style that has additional things that you do not need, it is hard to give any advice other than don't do that, since you have shown no code.

Comment: See _What makes a good MWE_ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/90087

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always define your own pagestyles. See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\fancypagestyle{emptyhead}{                 % Define a new pagestyle
    \fancyhf{}                              % Clear header/footer
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}                 % Set pagenumber in footer
    \fancyfoot[R]{(No header on this page)}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{                     % Redefine style "plain"
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[C]{Header for plain-style pages}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}                           % Define fancy pagestyle for common pages
\lhead{Author's name}                       % Set left header
\chead{}                                    % Clear center header
\rhead{Document title}                      % Set right header
\lfoot{}                                    % Clear left/center footer
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}                            % Put pagenumber in right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Hocus}\thispagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage

\section{Pocus}\thispagestyle{emptyhead}
\lipsum[11-20]
\clearpage

\section{Bogus}\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[21-30]
\end{document}
```

The first page of section 1 uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`, with a special header in the center and the page number in the right footer. The first page of section 2 is set with `\thispagestyle{emptyhead}`, with no header and the page number in the center of the footer (which is what `\pagestyle{plain}` would usually look like. The first page of section 3 has neither header nor footer (`\thispagestyle{empty}`). All other pages use the normal `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Is that what you wanted to do?